# Javascript, HTML browse

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do a script but i don't know how to start. I have a folder on my web server with pictures. I need a script which will help me get access to that picture:

- Click link/button on the webpage
- Get a browse list only to folder with pictures (folder localy on the server)
- Assign path to var and load picture.

I was thinking about doing something similiar to gallery. 
Do you have any ideas or sugestions or maybe any link to examples to something similiar?

Comment: Two ways of tackling this: Purely client side, using JS or server side generation (PHP, NodeJS, etc.).  The pure JS side requires a format for your file names like IMG_X.jpg, where X is a number. With JS, you could generate the markup needed with a loop and just replacing X with the number. Pass the current page as a query string (site.com?p=1, site.com?p=2, etc.) and use JS to calculate what images to load based on that. You could use `on error` to determine if additional images are to be loaded (if you wanna live dangerously), or you could add a variable in the HTML for the last image.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the way that you are asking for. The Javascript isn't running locally on the server, it's running remotely in the browser, so it can't access anything locally on the server.

You could possibly use AJAX to request a directory list of the folder from the server, but the directory list feature is normally disabled in a web server.

To do something like this you would normally use code that runs on the server and generates the pages that you browse to. Platforms like ASP.NET or PHP can do that. As the code runs on the server, there is no problem accessing the folder on the server.